# Rails advanced sql query

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a model User thats has_many user_entitlements. I want to get all of the users that have a preview attribute and no user entitlements.

My code is currently:

```
User.where("preview is not null").keep_if {|user| user.user_entitlements.empty?}
```

This is iterating through all of the users and seeing if they have any user entitlements.

Is there a way I could do this in SQL to make it more efficient and avoid having to go through each user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Arel to build a query leveraging `NOT EXISTS`.

```
user_arel = User.arel_table
ue_arel = UserEntitlement.arel_table
User.where("preview is not null").where(
  UserEntitlement.where(ue_arel[:user_id].eq(user_arel[:id])).exists.not
)
```

I am making an assumption on your schema that `UserEntitlement` contains a `user_id` column.

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler, you can use `includes` to force a LEFT JOIN, then check for NULL:

```
User.includes(:user_entitlements).
     where("users.preview IS NOT NULL AND user_entitlements.id IS NULL")
```

Comment: If there is a large data set you will _often_ see better performance with `NOT EXISTS` over a `LEFT JOIN`. Source: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/ EDIT: Clarifying that you _often_ see better performance, taking into account PinnyM's comment below.

Comment: @DanReedy, that will depend on the DBMS and version - only the query optimizer can determine how performant it will be given a specific query and analytics.  The article you linked was from 3.5 years ago and is SQL Server specific.  I'm not sure if a current version of MySQL (or SQL Server) is any better in this respect, but that would need to be determined.

Comment: @DanReedy, I do prefer your approach BTW, however ActiveRecord makes this messy to write out by hand.  Too bad there isn't a gem to add this as native behavior, since this is a fairly common scenario.  Maybe someday...